# MOSFET analog switch, Transmission Gate, Bilateral switch circuit questions

Tags: mosfet, audio, guitar-pedal, analog-switch

Below is an LTSpice simulation of two attempts at a Mosfet bilateral switch or 'transmission gate'.
The plot shows the switch (onoff) going from 0 to 5v (in blue) and a sine wave audio signal being moved up or down by the two circuits.

What I was hoping to see is the sine wave, only between the blue lines, and nothing either side.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with these two circuits?

I know that I can use a CD4066 etc., or a relay, but now I've become obsessed with getting a working bilateral switch circuit.

[image]

Comment: What are the VDD/GND voltages to the 2 inverters? Also, bring the audio voltage down to VDD/2 +- 0.5 volt, thus well inside the rails.

Comment: The idea is to switch these from a 74 series chip, so 'onoff' is 0 or 5V. the audio signal is plus or minus 0.7v. Is this the problem, do I need to DC shift the audio signal so that it is above ground? The plot shows the transmission gate allowing the original zero centred AC Signal through correctly, it's when the switch is off that it goes all funny.

Comment: You show two circuits and the top one won't work because the substrate connections need to connect to power rails and not their respective sources.

Comment: Are you saying that I need a 4 pin mosfet? I've seen diagrams like that. They don't appear to exist in small signal varieties. Am I doing something unusual here? Further, I've no idea how to simulate that in LTSpice, or where to get someone elses attempt at it.

Comment: Here ya go. http://tinyurl.com/ych9u9uw

Comment: That's exactly the circuit. I can't see any details of the simulation when viewing this from my phone.  Do you have any idea of actual part numbers? I see this, which I could use : https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.aldinc.com/pdf/ALD1105.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjB-rK4spDdAhVDC8AKHcs7BekQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3P267Sw7FrJKhUjCzmmU_Y.  Also I found n-channel BSS83 which is an SMD. Just need to find P complimentary.. and an LTSpice model.

Comment: Vt or Vgs(th) =1.5V on both with matched RdsOn 50~100 Ohms

Comment: I don't suppose you'd know how to create a spice model of that would  you? He says cheekily :)

Comment: I think I've done it.

Answer (score 1):

After the helpful comments above I managed to crack it. So here for the good of humanity is an LTSpice simulation of a MOSFET transmission gate, switching on and off a sine wave sweep from 20Hz to 20KHz over two seconds.
If anyone can find a complimentary P-Channel MOSFET to the BSS83 that has a substrate pin, I would be eternally grateful.
Also if anyone could provide better parameters for the pmos model than the ones shown in the simulation below, please do :)

Note there are some small transients on switching which may cause popping, but this is surprisingly clean switching, better than is likely from a relay. There is some signal attenuation, but again, surprisingly little. I think this is actually viable as a cheap, fairly low distortion dual polarity audio switch. I am super pleased that I decided to stick with this, and post here for help.

[image]

Comment: Adding a 68nF capacitor to ground parallel to R3 removes the transients, making this clean switching.

Comment: Make that more like 2.2nF

Comment: MIC94030 MIC94031 MIC94050 MIC94051 are smd p-channel fets with substrate pin, may be complimentary to BSS83

Comment: Is this better than bilateral gate with e.g. CD4066?

Comment: @user2497 it turns out that there are almost no available components to implement your own bilateral switches. Since this post I've become pretty much expert at small signal audio switching. The 405x 4066 etc. Are excellent, and cheap.. there's also a way to switch audio with a jfet. Let me know what you're doing.. i can probably help.

Comment: Thanks! I like your build, but boardspace is restrictively small. I only need to switch a line-level stereo signal on/off. Looking at the CD4066, and considering also what capacitor values are recommended, to prevent audible popping on output. Your thoughts? I am flexible with regard to voltage (except it becomes too clunky to have a negative voltage supply), and have read elsewhere the CD4066 prefers 9V. Excuse my lack of clarity, I haven't built this circuit yet, just making notes.

Comment: see this : http://www.geofex.com/Article_Folders/cd4053/cd4053.htm
Generally you'll raise the 'zero' point of your incoming signal to half way between ground and your supply voltage. So, your input ground goes to your circuit ground. Your input positive (signal) goes into a capacitor (about 0.1uF) to remove dc offset, then after the capacitor you'll have a pull up resistor to half voltage. Then you can run your 4066 with 0 and 9v. The key to avoiding pops is properly biasing (pulling up/down) your signals as explained in the link above. Raise a question, I'll post a picture as an answer.

Comment: Is DC biasing really as simple as that?

Comment: Yeah.. capacitor removes dc offset.. resistor to some half way voltage re biases.. You'll need an output capacitor too then to remove the biad (usually 2.2uF poly or 10uf electrolytic) followed by a biasing resistor back down to ground.

Comment: Interesting, this will take up no space at all. I will read more, and return;)

Comment: Is it of considerable importance to use a linear supply (or a 9V battery), instead of a SMPS power source, for this type of project? Or can I just add a choke to my 9V line?

Comment: You'll need a quiet supply. The better SMPS supplies are fine. And you'll need (on your PCB) to put a few capacitors of various sizes to do some damping. There are a million topics on Stack Exchange about the choice of values.. Generally one large value electrolytic (240uF 16V etc) and a 0.1uF ceramic.

Comment: You can also look into using "ground planes" on your PCB. This is when you 'make a capacitor' out of your PCB by leaving the unused copper on both sides of the board, and tie say the top side to 9V and the underside to ground etc.

Comment: Thanks, it is much appreciated! :)